# Capturar nome do arquivo

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, arquivo

Tenho um form que eu procuro o caminho de um arquivo em `.mdb` (banco de dados do Access), porém eu queria saber como que eu posso limitar e pegar exatamente a *string* do arquivo entre a última barra do `OpenFileDialog` e o ponto do `.mdb`.

Até agora fiz esse formato:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "Database Files|*.mdb";

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         string dbfile = dlg.FileName;
         label1.Text = dbfile;

         string file_name = dbfile.Split('\\')[5];

         string first = file_name.Split('.').FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Eu gostaria que não fosse necessário chamar a última barra do diretório do 5º `array` (pois assim o item poderia estar em qualquer pasta, não necessariamente na quarta pasta do computador), e sim um dado dinâmico que conseguisse ler a última barra e o `.mdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a classe [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), nela você irá encontrar diversos métodos para trabalhar com arquivos

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(dbfile);
//Mostra o nome do arquivo
string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
//Mostra a extensão do arquivo
string fileExtension = fileInfo.Extension;
//Mostra o caminho completo do arquivo junto com o nome
string fileFullName = fileInfo.FullName;
```

Comment: posso transformar esse `Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Name);`em uma variável?

Comment: Vou editar o exemplo pra usar como variável

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma é usar um método já pronto como o [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_IO_Path_GetFileNameWithoutExtension_System_String_).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).